# How do I create SAS fixed-format output containing end-of-line control characters?

Tags: windows, sas, control-characters, end-of-line

I am using SAS's FILE statement to output a text file having fixed format (RECFM=F). 
I would like each row to end in a end-of-line control character(s) such as linefeed/carriage return. I tried the FILE statement's option TERMSTR=CRLF but still I see no end-of-line control characters in the output file.
I think I could use the PUT statement to insert the desired linefeed and carriage return control characters, but would prefer a cleaner method. Is it a reasonable thing to expect of the FILE statement? (Is it a reasonable expectation for outputting fixed format data?) 
(Platform: Windows v6.1.7600, SAS for Windows v9.2 TS Level 2M3 W32_VSPRO platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use `RECFM=F`? You can still get fixed length output with `V`:

```
data _null_;
  file 'c:\temp\test.txt' lrecl=12 recfm=V;

  do i=1 to 5;
    x=rannor(123);
    put @1 i @4 x 6.4;
  end;
run;
```

By specifying where you want the data to go (`@1` and `@3`) and the format (`6.4`) along with `lrecl` you will get fixed length output.

There may be a work-around, but I believe SAS won't output a line-ending with the Fixed format.